# Referring to dynamic columns in a postgres query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have something like this:

```
select sum(points) as total_points
from sometable
where total_points > 25
group by username
```

I am unable to refer to `total_points` in the where clause because I get the following error: `ERROR:  column "total_points" does not exist`. In this case I'd have no problem rewriting `sum(points)` in the where clause, but I'd like some way of doing what I have above.

- Is there any way to store the result in a variable *without* using a stored procedure?
- If I *do* rewrite `sum(points)` in the where clause, is postgres smart enough to not recalculate it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe PostgreSQL is like other brands of sql, where you need to do:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(points) AS total_points
    FROM sometable
    GROUP BY username
) t
WHERE total_points > 25
```

EDIT: Forgot to alias subquery.

Comment: No, Postgres does support the HAVING clause - see answer by Quassnoi.

Comment: While `PostgreSQL` does support the `HAVING` clause, this is a valid answer too (except that the subquery should be aliased). See no reason for downvoting it.

Comment: @Quassnoi - Agreed. I would RATHER use the `HAVING` for simple things, such as `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc., but if I'm doing some long-winded mathematical function for my alias, I'd rather set it in a subquery so my query looks cleaner/nicer.

Comment: @Bandi-T - My answer offers the only method to refer directly to the alias, where using the `HAVING` clause would require repeating the function. I do realize that the function wouldn't be recalculated, but sometimes referencing the alias makes a query MUCH more readable.

Answer (score 26):

```
SELECT  SUM(points) AS total_points
FROM    sometable
GROUP BY
        username
HAVING  SUM(points) > 25
```

`PostgreSQL` won't calculate the sum twice.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with PostgreSQL, but I'd think it would complain because the GROUP BY column isn't in the SELECT list.  Is this something PostgreSQL does differently?

Comment: `@Bob Jarvis`: no database I'm aware of will complain about a `GROUP BY` column not being in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thank you for that good news "PostgreSQL won't calculate the sum twice."

Answer (score 9):

You have error in statement:

```
select sum(points) as total_points
from sometable
where total_points > 25 -- <- error here
group by username
```

You can't limit rows by `total_points`, because `sometable` don't have that column. What you want is limit gouped resulting rows by `total_points`, computed for each group, so:

```
select sum(points) as total_points
from sometable
group by username
having sum(points) > 25
```

If you replace `total_point` in your example, then you simply chech if sum computed from all rows is bigger than 25 and then return all rows, grouped by username.

*Edit:*
Always remember order:

1. is `FROM` with `JOIN`'s to get tables
2. is `WHERE` for limit rows from tables
3. is `SELECT` for limit columns
4. is `GROUP BY` for group rows into related groups
5. is `HAVING` for limit resulting groups
6. is `ORDER BY` for order results

Comment: `PostgreSQL` does not allow aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @quassnoi I didn't know that. I tough that most RDBMS-es accept aliases

Comment: `@MBO`: of the major four only `MySQL` allows this. `Oracle`, `SQL Server` and `PostgreSQL` don't

Comment: @quassnoi Sqlite3 also supports aliases. That's where my mistake came from - i tought sqlite tries to mimic much of postgresql features and not add its own :-)